# I have a number of data sequences and I want to select the longest sequence out them using R

Tags: r

I am working on a large number of sequences (nucleotide sequences) and I want to select the longest sequence (the sequence with the biggest length)  out of them. 
My sequences are elements of a list. 
I am working on the R software.
Any help with the code? which functions to use?

Comment: First you need to write some code before we can help you with it. Also, include a sample of your data (`dput(your_data)`).

Answer (score 0):

If you list is named `l` use `sapply(l,length)` will return a vector with the length of each element in your list. To select the longest sequence use

```
s<-sapply(l,length) # or use s<-lengths(l) (Richard Scriven's comment)
longest<-l[[match(max(s),s)]]
```

Example :

```
x<-rnorm(100)
y<-rnorm(1000)
z<-rnom(10)
l<-list(x,y,z)
s<-sapply(l,length)
longest<-l[[match(max(s),s)]] 

length(longest)
[1] 1000
```

Comment: As of R 3.0 you can use `lengths(l)` to replace `sapply(l, length)`

Comment: @RichardScriven As of [R 3.2](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/NEWS.html)

Comment: Noted.  Wasn't sure about the version.  Thanks

Comment: No worries :) I am still on 3.1.3 and couldn't use it :P. I think it is time to switch